# memcpy Performance Varies Based on Whether the Destination Pointer Changes During the Loop

Tags: c++, memcpy

So I am working with an FPGA card to capture data coming off the network, and I am having problems copying the data to memory quickly enough. I use mempcy to copy the bytes from one location to another, but when I have it configured to increment through the available space I get an error saying that I'm not copying data out of the source quickly enough and it is getting overwritten by incoming data.

However, if I set the destination to be a static value (either an absolute number or a variable that does not change), I do not get the 'not copying fast enough' error. This is useless since I've been basically overwriting the data in the destination the entire time, but memcpy works fast enough.

Code sample (elements from vendor abstracted):

```
unsigned char *destinationBuffer = new unsigned char[500000000];
unsigned int destBuffer_current_size = 0;

while (!RingBuffer->IsEmpty()){
     //abstraction - get pointer to next unit to be copied from source buffer
     bytes = (char*)unitToBeCopied

     memcpy((void*)&destinationBuffer[destBuffer_current_size], (void*)bytes, 4096);
     destBuffer_current_size += 4096;
```

Things that have allowed memcpy to work efficiently enough but are not viable options:

Set the pointer to destinationBuffer[0]

```
memcpy((void*)&destinationBuffer[0], (void*)bytes, 4096);
```

Set the pointer to destinationBuffer[490000000] - means that accessing portions of the array that are significant distances from the head is not the problem

```
memcpy((void*)&destinationBuffer[490000000], (void*)bytes, 4096);
```

Use an int for the destination pointer, but do not increment it - means that evaluating a variable is not the bottleneck

```
memcpy((void*)&destinationBuffer[destBuffer_current_size], (void*)bytes, 4096);
destBuffer_current_size += 0; //ie destBuffer_current_size does not increment
```

Use an int that does not increment for the destination pointer, but add another int that does increment to the loop - means that the incrementor is not the bottleneck

```
 memcpy((void*)&destinationBuffer[destBuffer_current_size], (void*)bytes, 4096);
 second_destBuffer_current_size += 4096; //ie destBuffer_current_size does not increment, but a second unsigned int does, to eliminate the incrementing as the root cause
```

Things that have not worked:

- Changing the buffer size
- Changing (void*)&var[] to just &var[]

Why would not incrementing the destination pointer in memcpy make it work more efficiently, and is there a way to make it work while incrementing it?

Note: Yes, it would be faster if I could just swap pointers and be done with it. The source data is in a section of memory where it will get overwritten if not copied quickly enough.

Comment: This is likely caused by virtual memory not being paged in. Allocating memory will typically not physically page in the memory - that will only happen as you access the memory, and takes time. So if you use the same segment over and over, it'll be paged in after the first round, which makes this faster than running through the buffer sequentially. Try initializing the whole buffer to 0 after you allocate it, and see if that helps.

Comment: You might also want to look into your OS's APIs for allocating non virtual memory